# VM Ubuntu Start Application, run .sh file

Tags: ubuntu, virtual-machine

I want to run a .sh file located at my Desktop whenever my VM (Ubuntu as OS) is started. So I added the command "sh /home/UserA/Desktop/myJob.sh" into the command field of "Starting Application" on Ubuntu. Unfortunally, when I shut the VM down and start again, the programm is not running. But when I just type in the command in the shell, it works as it is supposed to do.
I just did it according to some manuals.

What could be the problem here? 
Thanks in advance

Comment: Did you find the solution ?

Answer (score 0):

Do your script run by this command by youself from terminal? Try it.

Also there is several places to do startup sh script:
https://askubuntu.com/questions/228304/how-do-i-run-a-script-at-start-up
https://askubuntu.com/questions/814/how-to-run-scripts-on-start-up

Comment: Hi, thanks for the link. I used exactly that link for doing it by myself. I redundantly insert the command already in several files, including /etc/profile, /etc/rc.local or /etc/init/myjob.conf as well as in Ubuntu's the auto start application, but it still doesn't start with the restart of my VM

Comment: May be you do something special that does not working in moment of startup ubuntu? Do you try add sleep instruction before your command?

Comment: How you check that your sh script dont run? You can add to him "echo > /home/user/check.txt and check after restart exist of this new file.

Comment: because the domaen job, which I start by this script, is not running in the task manager. If I just start my .sh script manually, the domain Job starts and is listed in the task manager

Comment: I meant that may be problem not in "system don't run sh on startup" vs "sh fail on execute on startup and you think that it don't run anytime".

Answer (score 0):

Open the file /etc/profile and add the following line to the end of it.

```
sh /home/UserA/Desktop/myJob.sh
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the link. I used exactly that link for doing it by myself. I redundantly insert the command already in several files, including /etc/profile, /etc/rc.local or /etc/init/myjob.conf as well as in Ubuntu's the auto start application, but it still doesn't start with the restart of my VM

Comment: make sure your script has execute permission for the current user.
use this command : sudo chmod +x /home/UserA/Desktop/myJob.sh

Comment: Should I just execute this command once and it is then valid forever ?

Comment: hm I've done it and I think I already done it before, but still doesn't start. Can there be another issue ? I inserted the "sh /path/to/my/sh/file.sh" into different files like /etc/profile, /etc/rc.local or /etc/init/myjob.conf as well as in Ubuntu's the auto start application, but still it doesn't start when I restart the VM.

Comment: after logging into the server type `sudo su` and check whether anything is coming up.

Comment: Have to type in the passwort after typing in "sudo su"

Comment: after entering the password , are you able to see the output of your script?

Comment: yeah, I mean I can see the output of the script, which is running a daemon job

Comment: Create a file with any name in /etc/sudoers.d/ and add the following inside it `UserA ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD:ALL` . then replace `sh /home/UserA/Desktop/myJob.sh` with `sudo sh /home/UserA/Desktop/myJob.sh`